# mcu8051ide Missing existing library itcl3.4 (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: tcl, microcontroller, simulator, 8051, itcl

Issue is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448239/mcu8051ide-on-linux-mint-19-not-working-or-opening). As suggested I used tcl8.6, the application worked, but having problems with user interface like glitching UI and not working arrow keys (someone suggested [here](http://mcu8051ide.sourceforge.net/forum?forum=0&thread=259) to use tcl8.5 to solve some of these issues). But when I try to run it on 8.5, it is unable to find itcl3.4, even it is installed, and it is working with 8.6. Question is how could I use itcl with tcl8.5 for this application?

I am asking this new question rather than commenting in the given question due to insufficient reputation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`mcu8051ide\` on Linux mint 19 not working or opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448239/mcu8051ide-on-linux-mint-19-not-working-or-opening)

Comment: Issue is exact, but this is not a great solution due to the application is built as a tcl8.5 application rather than 8.6 ([cite this link](http://mcu8051ide.sourceforge.net/forum?forum=0&thread=259)). Having it run with 8.6 causing some other undesired behavior.

Comment: But the post contains the pieces needed to fix it for Tcl 8.5 (untested): (a) make a copy of `/usr/share/mcu8051ide/lib/main.tcl`, and, before the `package req itcl` line, add the following line: `package ifneeded Itcl 3.4 [list load [file join /usr lib x86_64-linux-gnu "libitcl3.4.so.1"] Itcl]` ... then run your copy of `main.tcl` using `tclsh8.5 main.tcl`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible to run itcl with tcl8.5?

Presumably, otherwise `mcu8051ide` as a Tcl 8.5 only application would not advertise, require it, right?

What about running

```
sudo apt-get install itcl3
```

(This should give you incrTcl/itcl 3.4.*.)

Comment: It says itcl3 is already installed then. I think I did not made it clear, the library is installed, but the application is not able to find it while using 8.5. It can find when 8.6 is used.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to make this clear pls.